# set selected value for AUTO POPULATED select box in jquery

Tags: jquery, set, drop-down-menu

i have 2 select box on my page named [Municipality] and [brgy] but the [brgy] select is auto populated by what ever the user selects on [Municipality] select box using change() event in jquery..the following are my code for this..

This is for the Municipality select box that populates the brgy select box

```
$("select[name='Municipality']").change(function(){ 
// get the selected option value of country
var optionValue1=$(this).val();                             
$("#Dbrgy")
.html('ajaxLoader.gif')
.load('all.php', {Muni:true, MunVal: optionValue1, status: 1}, function(response) {                 
if(response) {
$("#Dbrgy").css('display', '');
} else {
$("#Dbrgy").css('display', 'none');
}
});         
});
```

and this is the all.php that process the request

```
<?if(isset($_POST['Muni']))
{
$value = $_POST['MunVal'];
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_brgy` WHERE `brgy_id`='$value'");
?>
<select name="brgy" id="brgy"class="input" style='width:150px;'>
<option value='0'>&raquo;SELECT</option>

<?while($result=mysql_fetch_array($q)){?>
<option value="<?php echo $result['brgy#'] ?>"><?php echo $result['name'] ?>
</option><?}?>
</select>

<?}?>
```

now after populating the brgy select box i need to set selected value on it that was retrived from mysql database.

and this is how i set the selected value from database

```
if(isset($_POST['RetrieveUpdate']))
{
$qure=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_touristspot` where `spot_id`=$_POST[Id]") or die (mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($qure))
{
echo"<script> $('#brgy').val($result[brgy]);</script>";
}
```

but that seems not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: my goal is to set values of the 2 select box [brgy]-auto populated select box  and [Municipality]-a normal select box.. the info that should be set for these select box will be retrieve from database..the setting of value of [Municipality](a normal select box) works fine BUT the [brgy] didnt set the retrieved values..

Answer (score 1):

i have solved this problem... the problem with auto populated select box is you must first set value for the first  then the second  will be filled correspondingly with the values of first ... i figured out that when i set time delays in it,it actually sets all desired values the i solved this with my algorithm

```
>set value to the first <select> and trigger it to change($('#select').val('values   here').trigger('change');)
>then make some delay (settimeout(function(){},700);)
>then set the value of the auto populated <select>change($('#select').val('values here').trigger('change');)
```

that will works fine=)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the result of your sql query, I expect the problem might be this line...

```
echo"<script> $('#brgy').val($result[brgy]);</script>";
```

needs quotes around val like this

```
echo"<script> $('#brgy').val('$result[brgy]');</script>";
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... i tried what your answer but still it doesnt set any value at all..